# DynamoDB range keys exceeded size limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

When I do a table.put_item I get the error message "Aggregated size of all range keys has exceeded the size limit of 1024". What options do I have so I can save my data?

1. Change a setting in DynamoDB to allow a larger limit?
2. Split or compress the item and save to DynamoDB?
3. Store the item in s3?
4. Use another kind of database?
5. Other options?

Here is the specific code snippet:

```
def put_record(item):
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('table_name')
table.put_item(Item=item)
```

Here is an example of an item stored in DynamoDB. The two string variables p and r combined could be up to 4000 tokens.

```
{
  "uuid": {
    "S": "5bf19498-344c"
  },
  “p”: {
    "S": “What is the next word after Mary had a”
  },
  “pp”: {
    "S": "0"
  },
  "response_length": {
    "S": "632"
  },
  "timestamp": {
    "S": "04/03/2022 06:30:55 AM CST"
  },
  "s": {
    "S": "1"
  },
  "c": {
    "S": "test"
  },
  "f": {
    "S": "0"
  },
  "t": {
    "S": "0.7"
  },
  "to": {
    "S": "1"
  },
  "b": {
    "S": "1"
  },
  "r": {
    "S": “lamb”
  }
}
```

I read this
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ServiceQuotas.html
and couldn't figure out how the 1024 is calculated but I'm assuming the two string variables are causing the error.

The put_item doesn't cause an error when Item is a smaller size; only when the size is larger than the 1024 limit.

It is hard to estimate how many of the saves will be large but I need to be able to save the large items. So from an architecture perspective willing to consider any and all options.

Appreciate the assistance!

Comment: Max item size in DynamoDB is 400KB - can you please share an example of the value of `item`? What are specifying as the sort key? Are you inadvertently setting the partition ("primary") key as the sort ("range") key?

Comment: Partition key is uuid and it is a string. Sort key is p and it is a string. I added an example of an item record stored in DynamoDB to the post.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Aggregated size of all range keys has exceeded the size limit of 1024" is baffling because there can only be one sort key, so what does "aggregate" refer to? The following post was also surprised by this message: https://www.stuffofminsun.com/2019/05/07/dynamodb-keys/.

I am guessing you actually do try to write an item where its "p" (which you said is your sort key) itself is over 1024 characters. I don't see how it's the size of p+r combined that matters. You can take a look (and/or include in the question) at the one specific request that fails, and check what is the length of p itself. Please also double-check that you really set "p", and not something else, as the sort key.

Finally, if you really need sort keys over 1024 characters in length, you can consider Scylla Alternator - an open-source DynamoDB-compatible database which doesn't have this specific limitation.

Comment: That post helps clarify the error message! I tested when p is small and r > 1024 and it works fine. I tested it when p > 1024 and r is small and it gave the same error every time. Therefore, it looks like p can not be > 1024. I double checked and p is the sort key. If I want to be able to save p when it is > 1024 can I/should I change the sort key to something else (and not r since I want that to be > 1024 when applicable)? What I'm thinking of doing is creating a new field call it 'topic' and use that as the sort key so I can save p when it is > 1024.

Comment: So you're confirming my response that your problem is that p is longer than 1024 bytes, and r (or the sum of p and r) doesn't matter?
Anyway, yes - if you can model your data so that you have a shorter sort key, it will work. I don't know what your data includes, so I can't make any specific suggestions.